# $\sigma$-compact subgroups generated by union of countably many $\sigma$-compact subgroups

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

I see a proposition which states

> The union of countably many open $\sigma$-compact subgroups generates an open $\sigma$-compact subgroup.

The proof in the text is summarized as

> The union of countably many open $\sigma$-compact subgroups can be denoted by $(K_{n,j})_{n,j\in\mathbb{N}}$ where $K_{n,j}$ is a compact subset and $\cup_{j\in\mathbb{N}}K_{n,j}$ is an open $\sigma$-compact subgroup. Then the group $G$ generated by the family $(K_{n,j})_{n,j\in\mathbb{N}}$ is **therefore $\sigma$-compact**.

I guess I don't understand how the **$\sigma$-compactness** comes. In my opinion, the generated $G$ is just the union of multiplications of finitely many elements of the family $(K_{n,j})_{n,j\in\mathbb{N}}$ and their inverses. I see the multiplication of compact subsets is compact. However,

> the family is of size $\aleph_0$, so the number of subsets of the family is $2^{\aleph_0}$ which is uncountable, i.e., the union of those multiplications is a **uncountable** one, how could we say it is a **countable union** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $2^{\aleph_0}$ subsets of the family, but there are only $\aleph_0$ *finite* subsets of the family.  Every element of $G$ is a *finite* product of points in elements in the family and their inverses, so you only care about finite subsets (or really, finite sequences, since the order may matter).

Comment: Oh, you are right :-(

Comment: May I ask for another comment ? I guess the statement can be generalized to "The union of countably many open $\sigma$-compact **subsets** of a topological group generates an open $\sigma$-compact subgroup." That is, we don't need **subgroups** to generate subgroups, right ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.